# Can I get a Master's degree without a Bachelor's?

Tags: masters

I have over 15 years experience as a software developer. I completed 2 years of undergrad, but have been too busy to go back.

Now that I have the time, I looked into finishing my computer science bachelor's program. They told me I'd have to take English 101. (I'm too old for that)

Is there a way to skip the bachelor's program and go directly into a Master's program considering I have extensive CS experience and have been doing the same work as a bachelor's program graduate?

Comment: Some schools will accept real-life skills as coursework but I can't think of a school that will simply let you forego all requirements.  You also seem to be talking about one specific school.  You could shop around -- especially with all of the decent (and not-so decent) on-line programs around nowadays.

Comment: Just talked to one school (UMUC). Shouldn't I be worried about some of these on-line programs? I hear they aren't very credible.

Comment: Well that's why I said "decent and not-so-decent."  There are good ones out there.

Comment: Also, duplicate cited by ff524 has some good responses.

Comment: [b]WHY[/b]  are you "too old" to take ENG 101?  That seems very peculiar (I had a friend who taught Freshman English to a 73 year old man).